# How do I incrementally pipe print statements from my python command line app into a powershell processing chain?

Tags: python, powershell, pipeline

I would like my python command line app to incrementally pipe its output statements into a powershell processing chain. How can I change the below example python program to accomplish this?

---

test_pipeline.py

```
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for x in range(10):
        time.sleep(.5)
        print "did something: " + str(x)
```

---

To demonstrate the problem, please run the above program by executing the following:

C:\InPowershellPrompt>python test_pipeline.py | % { $_ + " but its not incrementally piped" }

The pipeline first collects all the print statements from test_pipeline.py and moves on to the next step only after test_pipeline.py completes.

Any thoughts on how to pipe the output from test_pipeline.py incrementally?

Comment: I/O buffering perhaps?

Comment: The pipeline is inherently synchronous. The only way that I am aware of to asynchronously pass information down the pipeline is through creating your own pipeline object in C# (or another .Net language) which gives you asynchronous access to the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So I guess there is no 'off-the-shelf' asynchronous pipeline trick I can use.

Comment: I haven't used it but google turned up this codeplex module that might help. In your case though, I doubt it. https://psasync.codeplex.com/